# Filter two python lists of similar dictionaries using key values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists of python dictionaries. I want to create a new list of similar dictionaries based on the difference between list1 and list2 using the key value 'fruit'. None of the dictionaries in either list are identical.

```
list1 = [
    {'fruit': 'apple', 'amt': '1'},
    {'fruit': 'banana', 'amt': '2'},
    {'fruit': 'cherry', 'amt': '3'},
    {'fruit': 'date', 'amt': '4'},
    {'fruit': 'elderberry', 'amt': '5'},
]

list2 = [
    {'fruit': 'date', 'amt': '6'},
    {'fruit': 'elderberry', 'amt': '7'},
]


list3 = [some kind of python list comprehension]

print(list3)

{'fruit': 'apple', 'amt': '1'}
{'fruit': 'banana', 'amt': '2'}
{'fruit': 'cherry', 'amt': '3'}
```

Comment: OK, what's the question? What do you need help with? If you haven't already tried solving the problem yourself, do that first. See [ask].

Comment: What's the criterion exactly? Is it dicts in `list1` that don't have a match in `list2`, or is it dicts in both lists that don't have a match in the other?

Comment: printing (list3) gives the example output that I am trying to achieve. I wrote pseudo code to illustrate the objective rather than explain it.

Comment: @PinAppleRedbull what if `list2` also contained `{'fruit': 'fig', 'amt': 8}` ? Should that item appear in the result?

Comment: So you want all the dictionaries that are in `list1` as long as nothing with the same fruit name is in `list2`? Is it possible that there could be a fruit in `list2` that isn't in `list1`, and if so, would you want that in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear if you would want `list3` to contain dictionaries only from `list1` if they're not in `list2` or also from `list2` if they're not in `list1`.

But basically you want either a *difference* or a *symmetric difference* of dictionaries in `list1` and `list2` based on the values in key `fruit`.

**Difference** contains items that exist only in the first set, and not in both sets.

If your lists only had the values of `fruit` in them, you could create sets out of them and do the difference using python's built in function: `list1.difference(list2)`. But as they're dictionaries with key-values that we want to ignore, you need to do it manually. List comprehension works:

```py
list3 = [x for x in list1 if x['fruit'] not in [y['fruit'] for y in list2]]
```

I.e. for items in `list1`, return item if its `fruit` is not in a list of `fruit`s from `list2`.

**Symmetric difference** contains a mix of items that are not present in both sets

The list comprehension is basically the same but done both ways `list1.difference(list2) + list2.difference(list1)`:

```py
list3 = [x for x in list1 if x['fruit'] not in [y['fruit'] for y in list2]] + [x for x in list2 if x['fruit'] not in [y['fruit'] for y in list1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit inefficient but it works to check.

```
def find_dif(l1, l2, check_value):
    l3 = l1.copy()
    for i in l1:
        for z in l2:
            if i[check_value] == z[check_value]:
                l3.remove(i)
    return l3
```

it takes in the two lists of dicts then checks each value against the other list's. it then pops those values out of the first list then returns that.
Edit: it returns the amount from the first list.